# unable to set up the ec2 ubuntu instance for auto scaling

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, scalability

I went through enough number of blog post which actually guides how to set up the auto scaling platform. I am using the Ubuntu ec2 32 bit AMI. From which I am trying to scale the instances, I am trying to set up the auto scaling initially in a micro instance and after every thing goes fine I wanna implement the same thing in the production server. I am mentioning the problems which I am facing since morning

1)setting my the env_variables has become a major challenge 2)I am facing this problem "MalformedSOAPSignature: Invalid SOAP Signature. Failed to check signature with X.509 cert" 3) Can I use the aws EC2 instance itself to scale the infra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)  This should be fixed by setting up the environment variables and anything else you need and then creating a custom AMI for the auto-scaling.

2) Not enough information to answer this.

3)  Yes you can trigger scaling events via the API from the instances if necessary but I would strongly recommend using autoscaling policies linked to CloudWatch alarms if at all possible.